# Como bloquear a edição de um registro quando esta a ser editado por um outro usuario C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Em um sistema em rede(Vários utilizando o mesmo banco de dados), como faço para saber se algum usuário já esta editando o registro. Pois se no caso dois computadores editarem o mesmo registro ao mesmo tempo, ocorre um problema pois só serão salvas as alterações do ultimo usuário que editou.

Comment: User, como é uma edição feita por usuários, não vejo este tipo de controle como uma coisa boa, afinal você não tem como saber se o usuário que iniciou o processo de edição vai terminar ou informar que não deseja mais editar aquele arquivo. Talvez seja mais interessante para o usuário, ver as últimas alterações realizadas e o autor delas

Comment: @user18748, mas mesmo assim se você bloquear e depois liberar para edição, essa última alteração é que será validada. Às vezes nadar contra a correnteza não faz nenhum sentido. Mas veja o link do QMechanic73, eu li e acho que resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estiver usando o Entity Framework, utilize o Data Annotation [ConcurrencyCheck], que o próprio contexto irá lhe auxiliar a tratar a concorrência, verifique em http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/concurrencycheck-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx. Verifique também o link passado no comentário do @QMechanic73, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx